# for loop not respecting if condition

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with 3 lists. One list has the original values, another list has values to be added or updated to the original list, and another list that holds the new values. I have a function to check if a condition is true or not, if it is true it just increments the quantity of the items in the original list and doesn't add the element, if it's not true it adds the element to the list for new items, that in the end will be added to the original list. The thing is that, after some use, the function stops reacting to the condition and performs both operations, incrementing the value and adding a new one to the list. Do you guys know how can I can fix that?

```
void addToTable(List<CartProduct> cart) {

if (table!.items!.isNotEmpty) {
 for (int i = 0; i < table!.items!.length; i++) {
    final CartProduct cartProduct = table!.items![i];
 
    for (var element in cart) {
      if (element.productId == cartProduct.productId) {
      
        cartProduct.increment();
        
      } else {
        newItems!.add(element);

       
      }
    }
 
  }
  
  table!.items!.addAll(newItems!);
  newItems!.clear();
  saveTableOrder();
  notifyListeners();

    } else {
  table!.items!.addAll(cart);
  saveTableOrder();
 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:core';

void main() async {
  final table = Table(items: [
    CartProduct(productId: '1'),
    CartProduct(productId: '2'),
  ]);

  void saveTableOrder() {
    print('Saving table order...  $table');
  }

  void addToTable(List<CartProduct> carts) {
    if (table.items.isNotEmpty) {
      final newItems = <CartProduct>[];

      for (var cart in carts) {
        var found = false;
        for (var tableItem in table.items) {
          if (cart.productId == tableItem.productId) {
            tableItem.increment();
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!found) {
          newItems.add(cart);
        }
      }

      table.items.addAll(newItems);
      newItems.clear();
      saveTableOrder();
    } else {
      table.items.addAll(carts);
      saveTableOrder();
    }
  }

  addToTable([
    CartProduct(productId: '2'),
    CartProduct(productId: '3'),
  ]);
  addToTable([
    CartProduct(productId: '2'),
    CartProduct(productId: '3'),
  ]);
}

class CartProduct {
  final String productId;

  int quantity = 1;
  CartProduct({
    required this.productId,
  });

  void increment() {
    quantity++;
  }

  String toString() => 'id: $productId, quantity: $quantity';
}

class Table {
  List<CartProduct> items;
  Table({
    required this.items,
  });

  String toString() => items.toString();
}


// Saving table order...  [id: 1, quantity: 1, id: 2, quantity: 2, id: 3, quantity: 1]
// Saving table order...  [id: 1, quantity: 1, id: 2, quantity: 3, id: 3, quantity: 2]
```

Comment: Thanks Kherel, your solution did work, sort of. It works for the first item on the list, but when I add a second item, the second item keeps reproducing the behavior, it increments and adds a new one.

Comment: I've updated the answer.
You get the print if you add it to the dart sandbox.
Maybe you have an issue in another place...